# SQL COPY INTO is unable to parse a CSV due to unexpected line feeds in some fields. ROWTERMINATOR and FIELDQUOTE paramters do not work

Tags: csv, t-sql, parsing, azure-synapse, carriage-return

I have a CSV file in Azure data lake that , when opened with notepad++ looks something like this:

```
   a,b,c
   d,e,f
   g,h,i
   j,"foo

   bar,baz",l
```

Upon inspection in notepad++ (vew all symbols) it shows me this:

```
   a,b,c[CR][LF]
   d,e,f[CR][LF]
   g,h,i[CR][LF]
   j,"foo[LF]
   [LF]
   bar,baz",l[CR][LF]
```

That is to say normal Windows Carriage Return and Line Feed stuff after each row.
With the exceptions that for one of the columns someone inserted a fancy story like such:

```
foo

bar, baz
```

My TSQL code to injest the CSV looks like this:

```
COPY INTO 
    dbo.SalesLine 
FROM 
    'https://mydatalakeblablabla/folders/myfile.csv' 
WITH ( 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0d',    -- Tried \n \r\n , 0x0d0a here
    FILE_TYPE = 'CSV',   
    FIELDQUOTE  = '"',         
    FIELDTERMINATOR  = ',',       
    CREDENTIAL = (IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity')   --Used to access datalake
)
```

But the query doesn't work. The common error message in SSMS is:

*Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 2 (NAME) in data file*

I have no option to correct the faulty rows in the data lake or modify the CSV in any way.
Obviously it is much larger file with real data, but I took a simple example.

How can I modify or rescript the TSQL code to correct the CSV when it is being read?

Comment: Actually I just tried your script with my file and it worked - maybe I'm missing something, will double-check my file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated a similar file and uploaded it to my datalake and serverless SQL pool seemed to manage just fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK 'https://somestorage.dfs.core.windows.net/datalake/raw/badFile.csv',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        PARSER_VERSION = '2.0'
    ) AS [result]
```

My results:

[image]

It probably seems like a bit of a workaround but if the improved parser in serverless is making light work of problems like this, then why not make use of the whole suite that is Azure Synapse Analytics.  You could use serverless query as a source in a Copy activity in a Synapse Pipeline and load it to your dedicated SQL pool and that would have the same outcome as using the `COPY INTO` command.

In the past I've done stuff like written special parsing routines, loaded up the file as one column and split it in the db or used Regular Expressions but if there's a simple solution why not use it.

I viewed my test file via [online hex editor](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/), maybe I'm missing something:

[image]

Comment: I am connecting to my dedicated pool via SSMS using db credentials, but I get "Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'." when trying to run it. It's the same in Azure Synapse Analytics. However, if I run in serverless it works to read the rows (though it complains about utf-8 but that seems like collation problem).

Comment: So OPENROWSET won't work in dedicated SQL pool just now - try it in serverless SQL pools.  It's the one of the other engines available to you in Azure Synapse Analytics (along with Spark Pools and Data Explorer Pool, currently in preview.

Comment: You could use the serverless query as a source for a Copy activity in Synapse Pipelines.

Comment: Hi, so where are we up to?  I could get my sample file to work, and posted the hex editor structure of it.  I'm thinking you should create a similar example and just pare back the problem to the simplest repro possible.

Comment: Serverless query works just fine (either from Synapse Studio or via SSMS), I am able to read the data into views and it hasn't shown any error. I used the copy data wizard to create a pipe and could successfully export tables to both the dedicated pool and the azure sql server we have. However, having to copy views poses a new problem, that if new views are added (we have a trigger that creates DDL) one has to manually add them to the pipe. I want to materilize the views for querying, to avoid reading CSV over and over but automate. Sort of a seperate issue, but do you know a good method ?

Comment: Some kind of For Each activity in a Synapse pipeline where the items is dynamic from the sys views?  Andy Cutler is doing some stuff like that- have a Google.